# Dashboard - Graph return 503

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard

Since few days the Graph on the dashboard return Error 503 (ajax call to `DashboarController/tunnelAction` )

A report is created and contains the following (I removed sensitive data from the url):

```
a:5:{i:0;s:45:"Unable to read response, or response is empty";i:1;s:1042:"#0 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/lib/Varien/Http/Client.php(61): Zend_Http_Client->request('GET')
#1 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(100): Varien_Http_Client->request('GET')
#2 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->tunnelAction()
#3 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('tunnel')
#4 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web/index.php(90): Mage::run('en', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:546:"/index.php/admin/dashboard/tunnel/key/blablalba/?ga=DATA_DATA&h=HASH_HASH";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

- Does anybody experienced similar issue ?
- Maybe Google did some API changes, I google but found nothing ?